# Swift MVVM Binding (Using Boxing)

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

I am trying to implement MVVM Architecture pattern using [Boxing](http://rasic.info/bindings-generics-swift-and-mvvm/). I have done it simply by Adding the Boxing Class:

```
class Dynamic<T> {
typealias Listener = (T) -> Void
var listener: Listener?

func bind(listener: Listener?) {
    self.listener = listener
}

func bindAndFire(listener: Listener?) {
    self.listener = listener
    listener?(value)
}

var value: T {
    didSet {
        listener?(value)
    }
}

init(_ v: T) {
    value = v
}}
```

And then In the ViewController I have referenced a ViewModel, this is my View Controller:

```
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

// UI Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var emailLoginTextField: FloatLabelTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordLoginTextField: FloatLabelTextField!

var viewModel = AuthenticationViewModel()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    viewModel.user.email.bind{
        
        self.emailLoginTextField.text = $0
        
    }
    
}}
```

And This is my View Model:

```
class AuthenticationViewModel{

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

let serviceManager = ServiceManager()

var user = User()
func signupUser(email : String?, password: String?){
    
    
    let parameters : [String:String] = ["email":emailField, "password": password!, "system": "ios"]
    
    serviceManager.initWithPOSTConnection(server: Utitlites.getServerName(), parameters: parameters, methodName: "/api/user/register", completion: { (responseData , errorMessage) -> Void in
        
        let json = (responseData as AnyObject) as! JSON
        
        print(json)
        
        if ErrorHandling.handleErrorMessage(responseData: responseData).0 ==  true {
            
            self.defaults.set("userId", forKey: json["user"]["id"].stringValue)
            
            //self.userId.value = json["user"]["id"].stringValue
            
            self.user = User(json: json)
            
            
            
            
        }
        
    })
    
}}
```

And this is my Model:

```
class User{

var id = Dynamic("")
var name = Dynamic("")
var email = Dynamic("")

init(){
    
}

init(json: JSON){
    
    id.value = json["user"]["id"].stringValue
    email.value = json["user"]["email"].stringValue
    
}}
```

My Question is:

MVVM Architecture wise, is it right to access the model using this line in the ViewController:

```
viewModel.user.email.bind{

    self.emailLoginTextField.text = $0

}
```

Because I can see now that the View is accessing the Model which I think is not what MVVM Stands for. I need someone to clarify

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best practice to go about this (imo) and according to this raywanderlich [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWx8TtRBOfk) at `31:18` is to actually set the `Model` to be private, your VC doesn't need to know about it at all, only the `ViewModel`.

After that, set getters for the `Model` in the `ViewModel` like this:

```
var id: Dynamic<String> = Dynamic("")
var name: Dynamic<String> = Dynamic("")
var email: Dynamic<String> = Dynamic("")
```

And then, in your `ViewModel` also, set the User object to have a `didSet` notifier that will update the `ViewModel`'s data accordingly:

```
private var user = User() {
    didSet {
        id = user.id
        name = user.name
        email = user.email
    }
}
```

Now, you can access these properties only from the `ViewModel` instead of the `Model` directly:

```
viewModel.email.bind{
    self.emailLoginTextField.text = $0
}
```

Oh, and don't forget to set the properties on the `Model` to be just regular strings ;)